# Snowflake stored procedure. JavaScript out of memory error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Consumer app needs to fetch data from snowflake. I created a stored procedure.
JS side of it is very simple, executes SQL statement and then just maps rows' fields into js objects and returns an array. The problem I have is that if the dataset returned is huge i get this exception:
`Error: JavaScript out of memory error: UDF thread memory limit exceeded SqlState: P0000, VendorCode: 100176, QueryId`. Don't understand why it complains about UDF if I'm running SP.

I don't know beforehand how much data will be fetched for the date range. Not sure how to overcome it.

I tried to just run sql query directly with the same parameters to get the same amount of data and no issues. But it's a huge query, plenty of columns, several joins... I'd rather keep it blackbox for consumers. Though I can admit it works fine and is a solution for the moment.

How can environment running nodejs under the hood on snowflake side that executes the stored proc could be adjusted? Memory specifically?
I tried bigger warehouse. It didn't help.

Any other ideas or the way I use snowflake is wrong?

Comment: It depends on the SQL query, the mapping process and the data being loaded. If your script is trying to load huge tables with joins in memory while building objects, that can be a problem. Implementing pagination is one way of avoiding that. Otherwise, depending on the specific SQL library, it could be possible to receive results from the query one at a time instead of all at once, possibly allowing you to build the collection without having the whole result set in memory at the same time. It's sometimes called "buffering"

Comment: right, you mentioned everything that hits resources. i get that. but what drives the memory limit? is it data warehouse size? how can I get this info? I can certainly spend some time on figuring what is the max number of records it could process but that's guessing... If you could elaborate on your last sentence. maybe an example

Comment: I don't know about memory limit of nodejs processes in that context, but I can expand on the buffering, apologies if I say stuff you already know. Generally, an SQL client will receive the whole result set from an SQL server. That have caused me out of memory exceptions in the past. One way around it is to use a generator function, that is, a facility that will expose only one row of the result set to the calling code at a time, effectively allowing you to manage it without busting memory. That should be a parameter used when creating the database connection, something like buffered queries.

Comment: nah, no need to sorry. just wanted to mention that on the same page with you and thought about it too. I updated my question. I meant nodejs on snowflake's side that executes the SP. It's evident that nodejs runs those under the hood

Comment: I'm not sure of the details of the use case, but have you investigated using a reader account and a secure view? That would give consumers access to run the query but it would look like a table to them and not expose any of the query logic. If you need to use Javascript to return something that large, rather than a SP you may want to look into UDTFs -- user defined table functions. That will probably help you get around memory limitations because it's processing by row.

Comment: I mentioned JS only because currently snowflake SPs support only JS and use nodejs under the hood to execute. Thanks for suggestion. I'll take a look